# Why do array type become tuples?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a problem with typescript

```
function watches<T extends unknown[]>(
  sources: [...T],
  cb: (value: T) => any,
){

}

watches([{a:1},'1'],(b)=>{})  // b -> [{a: number}, string]
```

this is exactly what i want, but why?

why `(value: T) => any` value is a tuple?

i feel it incredible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* I understand your question.

`(value: T) => any` this isn't a tuple.

This is an anonymous function.

The parentheses in the type are not the same as the parentheses around a tuple.

This would be like defining a function...

```
function myFunction(value: T) => any
```

The type of this function is...

```
(value: T) => any
```

Comment: Oh, I see.`[{a:1},'1']` is a tuple, isn't `(string | { a: number })[]` . Thanks

Comment: Oh wait… I see… the array result at the end is not triple. It’s just an array with an object at the first index and a string at the second index.

Comment: My understanding is: if `sources: T`, `[{a:1},'1']` is `(string | { a: number })[]`, but `sources: [...T]`, `[{a:1},'1']` is `[{a:number},string]`